# Javascript Alert interfering with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, alert

I'm using JQuery Ajax to get a script from server.

```
$.ajax({
    url: src,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script",
    timeout: transaction_timeout
}).done(function(){})
.fail(function() { alert("Error in server");})
.always(function() {Aegis.end();});
```

Then server returns a callback function that I will need to overide it, in order to get the results like :

```
function callbackfunction(msg){
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    var result = obj.result;
}
```

Everything is working fine, untill I put an alert in my callback function

```
function callbackfunction(msg){
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    var result = obj.result;
    alert(result);
}
```

Now, if user doesn't click OK before of time out, a time out failure will happen and "Error in server" will be alerted.

While, if callbackfunction is called it means that my transaction is done successful. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: *"Then server returns a callback function that I will need to overide it"* How does the server return a function? Please give a more complete example. I have no idea how `callbackfunction` is going to be called here and how it could create issues.

Comment: It returns something like : callbackfunction(msg) which msg is a json object including the results. In Java webservice it would be something like    out.print(callbackfunction+"'"+message.toString+"'");

Comment: Ah, so the response is JSONP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be this :

```
setTimeout(function(){alert(result);},0);
```

but the best one would probably be not to use `alert` at all. Why aren't you using [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) ?

EDIT : If what you want is to display a message in a simple way, that's not so hard :

```
$('<div>').text('message!').css({position:'fixed', top:0, background:'yellow'})
.click(function(){$(this).remove()}).appendTo(document.body);
```

(the message disappears when you click it)

Comment: That's just a sample code and we are demonstrating functions to our users. I need to keep it as sample as possible. They need to see the result in browsers :D!

Comment: You could still use custom way to show message to your user without blocking browser

Comment: @NilNull It happens because jQuery's ajax clears the timeout when the callback you gave to ajax returns. Using setTimeout like I do simply enqueue the function (the alert) and lets the callback you gave to ajax end immediately.

Comment: Thanks and accepted. However, if I want to apply these changes I need to change tens of pages with their manuals :(

Comment: I don't know what you're doing but maybe this could help you : http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/